# Show 'log in' in user menu when not logged in

Tags: 7, users

I'm asking myself, where is the code that hides "My account" & "Log out" in the user menu? Just curious, to learn from that code. Any way to know where to search if you want to know something like this?

I added a "Log in" link to this menu, and I want to hide this when nobody is logged in.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you have something that happens with a link, you need to look in the code for a `hook_menu()`.  Then you need to guess which module it is in.  In this case, take a look at core User module:

```
function user_menu() {
  $items['user/login'] = array(
    'title' => 'Log in',
    'access callback' => 'user_is_anonymous',
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Note the `'access callback' => 'user_is_anonymous',` line.  This means that you can only do this if you are anonymous (ie, not logged in).  This means that you should just be able to make a menu entry with "user/login" as the path, and the link will only show when you are logged out.

Answer (score 16):

You can add a menu link to `user/login`, the access callback of that verifies that it is only shown to anonymous users. Just like `user/logout` is only visible for logged in users.

The definition of these callbacks() are, as mentioned in the other answer, in [`user_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_menu/7)

Comment: +1 and the same is true for `user/register` - create the link the usual way through the menu UI, and it only appears for users who aren't logged in automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Check the menu definitions in [`user_menu()`](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/b9127101ffeca819e74a03fa9f5a48d026c562e5:/modules/user/user.module#l1587) in user module. The access callback determine, when will the menu item be shown.